# Give an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof to show that for any positive integer $n$ we have $\begin{align} \lim \frac{1}{x^n} =0 \end{align}$ as $x→\infty$.

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Give an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof to show that for any positive integer $n$ we have $\begin{align} \lim \frac{1}{x^n} =0 \end{align}$ as $x→\infty$.

How would you incorporate $\epsilon$-$\delta$ formalism to prove this limit?

Also on a side note, if one part of a limit of the function is approaching negative infinity, and on the right side of the limit it's a point, would it be considered as a infinite discontinuity?

Comment: I changed $\epsilon-\delta$ to $\epsilon$-$\delta$.  Putting the hyphen inside MathJax makes it appear as a minus sign rather than a hyphen.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. We wish to show that for all $x$ sufficiently large, the inequality $$\left|\frac{1}{x^n} - 0\right| < \varepsilon$$

is satisfied. Rearranging, we find that this is equivalent to requiring that

$$x > \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\varepsilon}}.$$

This shows that whenever $x$ is large enough (i.e. $x$ exceeds $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\varepsilon}}$), the desired quantity is $\varepsilon$-close to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $0 < 1/x^n \leq 1/x$ for any $x \geq 1$ and $n \geq 1$. So your $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof only needs to work for $n = 1$, and it will automatically work for all $n \geq 1$. Also, $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proofs are traditionally defined for the case when $x \to x_0$ for finite $x_0$. If $x \to \infty$, then you need to show your function is within $\epsilon$ of your given limit when $x$ is sufficiently large (i.e. $x \geq N$ for some $N$)